# Listing last 3 days items in directory using PHP

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code to list data from a directory folder, my question is how do I just list the values for the last three days? 
Secondly, Just asking but is it possible to add pagination to this code?

```
<?PHP

  function getFileList($dir)
  {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
      if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry/",
          "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => 0,
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry",
          "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }
?>

<h1>Display PNG images in a TABLE</h1>

<table class="collapse" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Size</th><th>Last Modified</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?PHP
  $dirlist = getFileList("./images");
  foreach($dirlist as $file) {
    if(!preg_match("/\.png$/", $file['name'])) continue;
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td><img src=\"{$file['name']}\" width=\"64\" alt=\"\"></td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['name']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['type']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>",date('r', $file['lastmod']),"</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to list files that were modified less than 3 days ago

```
if(!preg_match("/\.png$/", $file['name'])
  || $file['lastmod'] > strtotime('-3 day')
) continue;
```

If you want to add pagination, you should put the filter in `getFileList` instead of on display so you can easily count the # of displayable items you have.

Comment: THanks bout touching the topic of pagination, You are saying the pagination code goes into the getFileList..?

Comment: @dames I was referring to your `$retval` array. It currently contains all files and you then filter non png and images older than 3 days on display. For pagination you'll need to move the filter to your `getFileList` function, so that `$retval` will only contain the images you want to display. Once you have that you can use `count` and `array_slice` to figure out which images to display depending on which page you're on.